# Error Quota 'C2_CPUS' exceeded. Limit: 0.0 in region us-central1

Tags: google-compute-engine

Im new creating virtual compute in google services, but when I try to create and click in the create button after few seconds showme this error:

Quota 'C2_CPUS' exceeded. Limit: 0.0 in region us-central1.

Im trying to create a new virtual server with centos OS, 8vcpu 32gb ram and SSD disc,

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

As per the GCP article [here](https://cloud.google.com/network-connectivity/interconnect-quotas), I think that the issue is related to the project quota. I would like to suggest you to increase the quota, please follow the docs [here](https://cloud.google.com/network-connectivity/interconnect-quotas#requesting-additional-quota) to increase the quota.